# Incorrect HMAC when Base64 encode contains symbols

Tags: android, json, rest, base64, hmac

I am writing an android app that uses a RESTful API with JSON. In this process i take a query string and compute HMAC using the SHA-256 algorithm. I then Base64 encode the resulting hmac string and the original query string, and send them to my server API through json objects. Sometimes this works perfectly fine, sometimes i get an hmac incorrect response from my server. I am not the person coding the server, yet we are both pretty stumped as to why this is. The error only occurs when the already encoding hmac string contains a symbol, such as '+' or '/' or alternatively '-' or '_'. Any help or insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the server I am working with did not use the URL safe flag when generating hmac (uses "+" and "/" instead of "-" and "_") and this was causing the HMAC to yield blank spaces, " ", in place of the "+" symbol on the server side, despite having produced the "+" symbol on the Android App. The issue was solved when the server made some change of content that I do not know. The problem was solved and the application works consistently.